# CNN for colorization, about 128000 images, memory error

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to implement a CNN for colorization of gray scale images. I've been following a report by R. Zhang and everything seems to be working, at least to some extent. The problem is that I have based my code around using 5000 images with 64 x 64 pixels, that is, I'm currently reading in a numpy array of dimensionality (5000 x 64 x 64). What I want to do is to use about 128 000 images instead (of course it will take longer time etc, but that will be a problem for the future). I'm also trying to do a softencoding of the color labels for these images, and the problem is that I end up with a memory error when trying to use 128 000 images. My question is therefore, is there something that I can change about my code (using tf placeholders etc) to avoid this memory error I'm getting?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, UpSampling2D, BatchNormalization, Dropout
from skimage import color
import cv2 as cv
from keras.regularizers import l2
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K

class network:
    def __init__(self, points_n, epochs, batch_size):
        #self.points_n = points_n
        self.interpolation_factor = 4
        self.x = self.load_databatch()
        #self.epochs = epochs
        #self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.Q = np.load('pts_in_hull.npy')
        #self.v = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.load('prior_probs.npy').astype(np.float32)) / 101.378494
        self.sigma = 5
        #self.Z, self.L = self.soft_encode()


    def unpickle(self, file):
        with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
            dict = pickle.load(fo)
        return dict

    def load_databatch(self):
        d = self.unpickle('train_data_batch_1')
        x = d['data']
        area_img = int((x.shape[1]) / 3)
        x = np.dstack((x[:, :area_img], x[:, area_img:2 * area_img], x[:, 2 * area_img:]))
        self.h = self.w = int(np.sqrt(area_img))
        x = (x.reshape(x.shape[0], self.h, self.w, 3))
        #print(x.shape)
        return x

    def gaussian_kernel(self, x):
        return np.exp(-0.5 * ((x**2)/(self.sigma**2)))

    def soft_encode(self):
        nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=5, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(self.Q)
        self.new_h, self.new_w = int(self.h / self.interpolation_factor), int(self.w / self.interpolation_factor)
        #Z = np.zeros((self.x.shape[0], self.new_h, self.new_w, self.Q.shape[0]))
        Z = []
        L = np.zeros((self.x.shape[0], self.h, self.w, 1))
        row_idx = np.arange(self.new_h * self.new_w).reshape(self.new_h * self.new_w, 1)
        for i in range(self.x.shape[0]):
            cie_img = color.rgb2lab(self.x[i])
            l = (cie_img[:, :, 0] -50) / 50
            l = l.reshape((cie_img.shape[0], cie_img.shape[1], 1))
            L[i] = l
            resize_img = cv.resize(cie_img, (self.new_h, self.new_w),
                            cv.INTER_AREA)
            ab_channel_img = resize_img[:, :,1:3].reshape((self.new_h * self.new_w, resize_img.shape[2]-1))
            distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(ab_channel_img)
            knn_Y = self.gaussian_kernel(distances)
            knn_Y = knn_Y / knn_Y.sum(axis = 1, keepdims = True)
            z = np.zeros((self.new_h * self.new_w, self.Q.shape[0]))
            z[row_idx, indices] = knn_Y
            z = z.reshape((self.new_h, self.new_w, self.Q.shape[0]))
            Z.append(z)
        #return np.array(Z), L
        print(np.array(Z).shape)

network1 = network(500, 1, 50)
#network1.load_databatch()
#network1.soft_encode(
```

)

Comment: Perhaps I should've added that I do believe the problem comes from going from RGB-color space (integers), to the LAB-color space (floats) with the dimensionality I have. (perhaps someone else has a better suggestion of what it might be)

Comment: error with backtrace?

Comment: I do believe my question could be reformulated, is it possible when using Keras and building a neural network, to not give the entire input at once but rather keep feeding it the batches?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. You have `train_batches`. You can also feed values using a generator and train your model with `fit_generator`.